# smaller size parameters affect setvbuf results?

Tags: c, io, stream, buffer

When I used setvbuf to change the **stream buffering mode**, I found that changing **[buffer]** and **[size]** parameters also affected the actual stream buffering behavior.And I don't know what caused it.

For example:

this is one of my testing code(All tests are to **cat myfile.txt** during sleep(100))

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *pFile;
  char *buf = (char *)malloc(20);
  char *str = "abcde";
  pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
  setvbuf (pFile,buf,_IOLBF,20); //change [buffer] and [size] parameter will get unexpected behavior. 
  fwrite(str,sizeof(char),strlen(str),pFile);
  sleep(100);
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Here the buffer mode is set to **_IOLBF**.So,as expected,we won't get anything when we **cat myfile** during sleep(100).

`XXX@Ubuntu:~$ cat myfile.txt
abcde`

And then I got this strange result. After that, I tried many different combinations and got the following results.

```
+ [stream] + [buffer]  +   [mode]  +   [size]   +   behave as [mode]
|          |           |           |            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  pFile   |    buf    |   _IOLBUF |    20      |       ×
|  pFile   |    buf    |   _IOLBUF |    200     |       √
|  pFile   |    NULL   |   _IOLBUF |    20      |       √
|  pFile   |    NULL   |   _IOLBUF |    200     |       √
|  pFile   |    buf    |   _IOFBUF |    20      |       ×
|  pFile   |    buf    |   _IOFBUF |    200     |       √
|  pFile   |    NULL   |   _IOFBUF |    20      |       √
|  pFile   |    NULL   |   _IOFBUF |    200     |       √
|          |           |           |            |
```

Finally, it was found that [size] was too small(but still larger than the length of **str**), so the result was different from that.

Why does a smaller parameter [size] cause this?

Comment: You must check the return value of `setvbuf`: _"If the buffer is correctly assigned to the file, a zero value is returned.
 Otherwise, a non-zero value is returned; This may be due to an invalid mode parameter or to some other error allocating or assigning the buffer."_

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks,but all the return value I've checked was 0